# React Native: Render issue with <Image> Tag inside <Text> tag

Tags: react-native, jsx

I need to render an `<Image>` inside a `<Text>` element. The reason is the usage of a CMS, but that is not really relevant to the problem at hand.

When the image is rendered inside `<Text>` on iPhone, it adds a background outline of a file icon:

```
    <Text>
        <Image source={require('../../assets/images/logo/heart.png')} resizeMode="contain"  style={{height: 120, width: 120 }}  />
    </Text>
    <Image source={require('../../assets/images/logo/heart.png')} resizeMode="contain" style={{height: 20, width: 20 }}  />
```

The first one creates a file outline, the second one renders correctly.
I need to render the image inside the text without the outline.

[image]

Comment: You may find it easier, if you place both in a view, and handle their position with styles by giving them absolute position

Comment: I can't separate the Image from the Text. It comes from another source.

Comment: why do you need text if you are showiing image?

Comment: It's a combination of text and image. I just took a screenshot of the image.